# Laravel 9 - pagination() pages results truncated

Tags: laravel, meilisearch

I already had this "problem" when using a local scope in the same model but i used another method to reach that specific goal.

Now, i want use MeiliSearch as search engine but i have the same problem as above: the paginated result are being truncated.
The pagination is set to 10.
The first page has 6 results, the second one has 2 results and the fourth page has 0 results.

```
Article::search($this->meiliSearchText)
    ->query(fn($query) => ($this->showSold == "true" ? $query->whereHas('sales') : ($this->showSold == "false" ? $query->whereDoesntHave('sales') : $query)))
    ->paginate($this->pagination)
```

I think this is cause because a filter is applied AFTER the query has been retrieved.
How should i treat this aspect?

**EDIT:**

In the documentation it's explicitly said that the "query" method should not be used for filtering result and i should use the Laravel Scout's "where" clause.

> Since this callback is invoked after the relevant models have already
> been retrieved from your application's search engine, the query method
> should not be used for "filtering" results. Instead, you should use
> Scout where clauses.

But honestly i can't get it to work even with that useless piece:

```
Article::search($this->meiliSearchText)
    ->where(function ($query) { return $query; })
    ->paginate($this->pagination),
```

It simply kills the page returning a 500 error.

**EDIT 2:**

Well.

> Since a search index is not a relational database, more advanced "where" clauses are not currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try `query()` by this way:

```
$query = Article::query();

$query->when($this->showSold == "true", function($q){
    $q->has('sales');
});

$query->when($this->showSold == "false", function($q){
   $q->doesntHave('sales');
});

$articales = $query->paginate($this->pagination);
```

and if you want to use `search` local `scope` then you can add that scope in fist line right after the `query()`. i.e.

```
$query = Article::query()->search($this->meiliSearchText);
```

if `search` still not work accordingly then move `search()` before the `query()` builder. i.e.

```
$query = Article::search($this->meiliSearchText)->query();
```

> Note please verify `true` and `false` is string or boolean type value and then compare those accordingly. if there type is string then enclosed a value in `double quotes` or if boolean then remove those `double quotes`.

Comment: The first block works pretty well! I never use the "never" clause, thanks for this new tip! The second one gives "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::search()" while the third returns "Too few arguments to function Laravel\Scout\Builder::query(), 0 passed"

Comment: have you imported `Laravel\Scout\Searchable;` in Article model and also added `Searchable` trait in class or not? [Laravel scout installation reference](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scout#installation). I hope that will work if you follow same installation procedure

Comment: Yes, anything installed. The search itself is not a problem but filtering the result with other fields other than simple text search.

Comment: hey have you tried `search()` before the `paginate()` because I think `search()` convert results to collection so you need to place filters before the `search()` i.e. `$articales = $query->search($this->meiliSearchText)->paginate($this->pagination);`

Comment: Paginate should always be the last chained method when paginating i think